# Java how to use XMLStreamReader and XMLStreamWriter in the same method

Tags: java, xml, stax

I use XMLStreamReader to read xml file. I want to copy this actual file and add somes nodes in this file :

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    
    try {
        XMLStreamReader dataXML = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(path));
        XMLStreamWriter dataWXML = (XMLStreamWriter) factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(path));
        
        while (dataXML.hasNext())
        {
            int type = dataXML.next();
            switch(type)
            {
                case XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT:
                    
                     dataWXML.writeStartElement("apple");
                        
                    break;
            }

        }
```

When I try to run I have this error : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl cannot be cast to class javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter`

What is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `XMLOutputFacotry` instead to create the output stream

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLOutputFactory outFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
try {
    XMLStreamReader dataXML = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(path));
    XMLStreamWriter dataWXML = factory.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileReader(otherPath));
    ...
}
```

Note the use of another path for the output file

Comment: I am also using the `XMLStreamReader` but facing some issues. I have posted the question with the sample code here. If you get a chance can you please have a look at this and provide your suggestions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67667516/stax-xmlstreamreader-check-for-the-next-event-without-moving-ahead

Answer (score 0):

This line is your problem:

```
    XMLStreamWriter dataWXML = (XMLStreamWriter) factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(path));
```

You simply cannot cast an XMLStreamReader to an XMLStreamWriter. They are separate classes and XMLStreamWriter does not extends from XMLStreamReader

Comment: I am also using the `XMLStreamReader` but facing some issues. I have posted the question with the sample code here. If you get a chance can you please have a look at this and provide your suggestions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67667516/stax-xmlstreamreader-check-for-the-next-event-without-moving-ahead